# The problems of cosimulation using opnet

Tags: c

please I would like you to answer me about that error when I compiled my C program(VC++ 6.0) Thank you very, I would appreciate any help .. Note :my program is to perform cosimulation between OPNET modeler 14.5 and VC++ by using external cosimulation controller C program ....
I set the use_esa_main to "yes" in the SD file. So, i need to get a .dll file. But when I use the VC++ to generate the .dll file , the errors come from :

```
Linking...
   Creating library Debug/ESA_DLL.lib and object Debug/ESA_DLL.exp$ESA_DLL.OBJ : error 
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Interface_Value_Set$ESA_DLL.OBJ : error 
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Interface_Value_Get$ESA_DLL.OBJ : error 
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Execute_Until$ESA_DLL.OBJ : error
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Interface_Callback_Register$ESA_DLL.OBJ : error 
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Interface_Group_Get$ESA_DLL.OBJ : error 
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Load$ESA_DLL.OBJ : error
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Init$Debug/ESA_DLL.dll : fatal error 
LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals$Error executing link.exe.
```

Comment: Are you building with all source files? It seems you are missing one or more source files.

Comment: Yeah, and I have already include the header file "esa.h". But it still don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the library of Opnet for co-simulation which is opsim.lib to your C program the these errors will disappear

Comment: how to add the opsim.lib to the co-simulation